# Clean URL using .htaccess and possible suggestions

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following url:

`http://mywebsite.com/somepage.php?product=343&type=4`

I want the user to be able to type:

`http://mywebsite.com/somepage?product=343&type=4`

the role should handle pages in sub-directories and different file names (Not just Somepage or subdomain). For example:

`http://mywebsite.com/subdomain/somepage.php?product=343&type=4`

can be accessed by typing:

`http://mywebsite.com/subdomain/somepage?product=343&type=4`

I am also wondering if such links can be even cleaner?

Comment: So, you want to remove the `.php`?

Comment: You can use `MultiViews` for avoiding just the .php extension. Otherwise, a `RewriteRule`. See [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) for examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will take any request that doesn't point to a file or directory and append ".php" if the .php file exists.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This should solve the problem by only rewriting the request when the destination file exists.

Comment: http://mywebsite.com/subdomain/some-non-php-file-that-doesnt-exist.php
 will return a 404 but the error message will say that "/subdomain/some-non-php-file-that-doesnt-exist.php" not found instead of the original request (sans .php).

Comment: I've updated the answer so that it checks for the destination file before rewriting. So `something` will point to `something.php`, but `non-existent` will just return a straight 404.

Comment: @JonLin: The handling for 404 is and should be separate. Redirect 404s to a custom error page to avoid exposing technology by creating a custom document then adding `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` to your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it might work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^somepage(.*)$ somepage.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

While the correct way is typically accepted as URL rewriting using .htaccess as @Nathan has shown, you can also optionally use `MultiViews` on a per-directory basis:

```
<Directory /home/www/sitename/htdocs>
Options + MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Multiviews, on 404 from an unknown file extension, will begin searching for a match in the filename. That is, if the URI is `foo`, it'll look for `foo.*`; that said, it could potentially find `foo.gif`, `foo.jpg`, `foo.html`, etc., and will return the highest quality option.

If you're certain you could provide all your content on a unique-name basis (shouldn't be hard), then by all means use this. Then just change all your anchors to direct to `somepage?product=343&type=4` instead of `somepage.php?product=343&type=4`

**edit**:

Yes, such links can be made even cleaner. Using URL rewriting, you could rewrite your URLs to:

`somepage/product/343/type/4` or `somepage/343/4`

This is done by the appropriate (respective) regex:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?product=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]
```